Flutter validate TextFormField with StreamBuilder from FirebaseFirestore
I'm trying to validate a TextFormField where I stream data from Firestore collection. The validation is **if the field "email" is equal to the TextEditingController email.text, it should return "email already exists.". But it always return this result even when the email does not exist.
      StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(widget.userCollection)
                  .where("Email", isEqualTo: email.text) //I even tried "Email", isNotEqualTo: email.text
                  .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 30),
                         child: AppTextfield.textFormField(
                         onChanged: (value) {
                         globalKey.currentState?.validate();
                   },
                   validation: (value) {
                   if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return widget.emailExist;
                    }
                   if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return (widget.emailRequired);
                   } else if (!RegExp(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+').hasMatch(value)) {
                      return widget.enterValidEmail;
                   }
                   
                   return null;
                   },
               ),
            );
        })


This approach won't work, because the snapshots won't update when the value of email.text changes. You need to request a snapshot in the validation section of your code, or - as is more common - after the user submits the email (to prevent querying on every character entered). Also, I believe snapshot.hasData is true also if the snapshot is empty, which would explain why it always says the email exists. You'd have to test on the snapshot being empty, not whether it has data - but per above that change won't solve your problem as your architecture is incorrect.
